# How to vertically center content in Ionic5 using Flexbox?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I want to vertically center all of the content inside my ion-content div. IE: have the same amount of space above and below. However it's not working. It currently shows the content split in half horizonally, completely ignoring the rows.

I'm tring to get the text and each input field to be its own row on the page and take up the full width.

[image]

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="subtext">
            <ion-col>
                Puzzles, Treasure and Fun
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(form)" method="post">
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label position="floating">UserName</ion-label>
                        <ion-input ngModel name="username"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="email" ngModel name="email"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="password" ngModel name="password"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-button type="submit" expand="full" color="danger">Register</ion-button>
                </form>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
ion-toolbar {
    --padding-start: 5%;
    --padding-end: 5%;
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --border-width: 0 !important;
    color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

ion-back-button {
    color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

ion-content {
    --padding-start: 5%;
    --padding-end: 5%;
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ion-item {
    --background: none;
}

.subtext {
    color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

ion-grid {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

needed to add

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: That saved my day, thanks!